# Custom Label Returning 401 for Guest Users - Vlocity CMT

Tags: experience-cloud, omniscript

Our Custom Labels (not part of the managed package) return a 401 error when we attempt to load them as Guest Users in our Experience Cloud Site.

The error message is:

```
core.apexpages.exceptions.ApexPagesGenericException: 401 status code return from request to https://service--XXXX.sandbox.my.site.com/myaccount/apex/vlocity_cmt__customlabeltranslation?labelLanguage=en_US&labels=...
```

The Custom Label is listed as a *Translatable Element* in the Omniscript we are attempting to display.

We attempted to add the domain of the site to CSP allowed sites

Comment: Hi Jordan,
Could you please check if you have marked that label as a "Protected Component" there is a known issue with that but not exactly like your case  see here https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAwXmAAK/error-thrown-when-the-custom-label-is-set-to-protected-component-and-accessing-the-custom-label-via-formula